# Flutter : Make IconButtons with different Icon sizes and Text elements in Row align to the center

Tags: flutter, styles, alignment, row, iconbutton

I have this `Row` widget in Flutter App with some `IconButton`s

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous,
        color: Colors.amber, size: 35),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          pageIndex = 1;
        });
      }),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left,
        color: Colors.amber, size: 45),
      onPressed: decIndex),
    Text('Page $pageIndex',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.amber,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right,
        color: Colors.amber, size: 45),
      onPressed: () {
        incIndex(pageNumbers);
      }),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next,
        color: Colors.amber, size: 35),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          pageIndex = pageNumbers;
        });
      }),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.location_searching,
        color: Colors.amber, size: 35),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          pageIndex = userPage;
        });
      }),
  ],
),
```

they display as shown in this image:

the red line is just to be clear the difference between elevations

I want make all items aligned on the same line through their center.
How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: I think what you're looking for is CrossAxisAlignment. You have to set it to center. Read the available options here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html

Comment: @Uni I used all CrossAxisAlignment values and i get same

Comment: That means the icon sizes are not the same. Take a look at someone's answer below.

Comment: @Uni The issue here is not with `Axis`. OPs icons are overflowing out of the `IconButton` since the `IconButton` is not adapting to the increased `Icon` size. I posted an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `size` parameter on the `Icon` is not a very good approach for `IconButton` widgets.
You icon are becoming big and the `IconButton`s are not adapting to that expanded size, which is causing the icon to overflow.

Instead, use the `iconSize` parameter on the `IconButton` and give the same value you were giving to the `Icon` and remove it from the `Icon`.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 35,
      icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous, color: Colors.amber),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          pageIndex = 1;
        });
      }
    ),
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 45,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left, color: Colors.amber),   
      onPressed: decIndex
    ),
    Text('Page $pageIndex',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.amber,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 45,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.amber),
      onPressed: () {
        incIndex(pageNumbers);
      }),
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 35,
      icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next, color: Colors.amber),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          pageIndex = pageNumbers;
        });
      }),
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 35,
      icon: Icon(Icons.location_searching, color: Colors.amber),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          pageIndex = userPage;
        });
      }
    )
  ],
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you too much ,yes it is solved many  thanks